# IOS App language not change on click button using LanguageManager-iOS-Lokalise0.1.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am using `LanguageManager-iOS-Lokalise0.1.3` library for changing app language. This works if i restart the App. I want to change app language at run time on click of button. How can I achieve that using `LanguageManager-iOS-Lokalise`.

Comment: Please share some code how you used

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible, because you need to re render the view controller. One way is to pop to rootView controller and after language change.
P.S you need to change `.semanticContentAttribute`  to `.forceRightToLeft` for all class you want to change RToL